# Android library project custom redirect

Tags: android

I’ve an android app and checked as library let it be Mainapp. Now I have created two separate app using that library viz. subapp1 and subapp2. Individual apps are running fine. I’ve login activity in the library package. On successful login user will be redirected to dashboard activity.
Written simply in loginactivity page of the library pack

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), UserhomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Now I need to specify to which activity the user will be redirected based on the sub app. So how I can manage this without replicating the pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could provide the class and package name as an argument and start a new intent:

```
Intent sccuess = new Intent();
sccuess.setClassName(packageName, className);
startActivity(sccuess);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly but If I understand you correct, you need to derive your activities from `SecureActivity` which user is supposed to be logged in to access there.

After you extend your classes from `SecureActivity`, you can check it in `onResume()` method.

Here is an example:

```
public class SecureActivity extends Activity
{
 @Override
 public void onResume()
 {
   // Check if user logged in or not.
 }
}

public class YourActivity extends SecureActivity
{
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Mainifest of your Library, your should define like that

```
<activity
    android:name="com.gmail.app.activities.A_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" > 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gmail.app.A.Fire_Activity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.gmail.app.activities.B_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" > 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gmail.app.B.Fire_Activity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In library code where to fire the intent:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(_context.getPackageName() + ".Fire_Activity"); 
    //Action will be like com.gmail.app.A.Fire_Activity or com.gmail.app.B.Fire_Activity

    startActivity(i);
```

PS:
Your Sub-Apps have package-names:

com.gmail.app.A
com.gmail.app.B